# Nuget Package manager's package source is not available in source

Tags: nuget-package, pagedlist

I have installed pagedList and PagedList.mvc. But it shows 'Not available in this source'. I added manually the .dll file and add to the reference. Still gets the error. 
And also in that computer, I have no internet connection.

Comment: I have solved it. I have manually added the packages from another computer (which had the packages) then added the reference. First I had not imported the full package folder.